# Orchard Contrib.Cache does not appear to do anything

Tags: orchardcms-1.6

We have just tried to enable Contrib.Cache on an Orchard 1.6 site (we can't upgrade right now, too close to a major launch).

I've enabled the module, but it appears to have absolutely no impact (currently testing out running from visual studio and IIS Express).

I've looked at the backend screens, but everything implies that there is nothing to change. I never see anything appear on the "statistics" tab.

I'm quite confused. Do I need to do something further to see any benefits? Nothing seems to happen at all

Comment: A correction to this. It is caching our access denied page and generic content pages. Just not anything else (our controllers and more complex pages). I can see all our routes listed on the caching admin page, they just don't seem to be affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is because the code for caching checks for a logged in user.

If you are logged in, it will not cache or show you caching. I guess in normal conditions this is good, but we were deliberately considering non-user specific pages when logged in, with the user specific bits loaded by script after the page response has been sent to the client.